# Dynamic feeds or manual feeds? (user activities)

Tags: design-patterns, feed

If a site in develop is supposed to grow a lot in the future (like millions of users), how should I manage the feeds (users' activities)?

1. For every user activity, I manually create a Feed record in some Feeds table
2. Deduce the feeds in the moment

A concrete example is the following:
Users are able to be followed by other users (like twitter) and they are able to create things. If I create a thing, this thing will have CreationDate and other stuff. I could feed my followers just using joins or by having a Feeds table that has to be updated in case someone stops following me.

Clearly (1) is difficult to mantain but faster, (2) is easier but I'm not sure it will handle so many users making joins for visibilities, etc...

How does it Facebook do it? or Twitter?

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the authors of Feedly a python framework that helps you building feed systems.

Feedly can be used to use full push approach or a mix of push and pull; in our documentation we provide plenty of references and explanations about this.

You can find the project on [github](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Feedly) and the background articles [here](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Feedly#background-articles)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a service to handle this for you, Collabinate (http://www.collabinate.com) may be what you're looking for.  It provides an API to create activity streams per entity, have users follow entities, then retrieve the real time feeds for users.  It is built to scale to the size you're looking at. Full disclosure: I am the creator of Collabinate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following structure:

**feed table** with fields feed_id, feed_type_id, creator_id, created_date, display_date, status, etc... where status is either active, hidden, or deactivated which you can use combined with updating the display_date field for handling unfollows and refollows without the need to create additional records

**feed_type table** with fields feed_type_id, feed_type_name

**follows table** with fields follow_id, feed_id, user_id

**post table** with fields post_id, feed_id, text

...and so forth for each feed_type

While it takes a bit longer to set up on the db side, in the long run this will save you time because each feed type can easily inherit all of the common fields such as creator_id, created_date, status, and display_date which will correspond nicely to classes in object oriented code and will be easier to look up. For example if you each user has a wall, then you just simply select from the feed table by creator_id, and for an activity feed of follower's activity, just select feed where creator_id is in the user's followers.

While you'll end up with more tables, you'll have less total fields to manage and less code to write. It's all based on Aristotle's theory of categorizing things by genus and species, that is by what the things have in common (genus) and their specific difference (species).